# Failed Dual Boot messed up my main operating system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, 21.10

The files are still there as it says there is 300 gbs of data, just when i boot into it, it says something about grove recovery mode or something, also there is no option to boot into ubuntu even though it says its installed, when I installed it, i created 2 partitions, one was a 10gb efi and a 30gb ext2 that "has" linux on it, when installing linux it gave me a "fatal" error then said it was finished (note, dont know much about linux, don't use advanced terms or stuff)

Comment: Can you edit your question with some details? You don't need to come up with any advanced terms, just use the terms that are presented to you. For example, give the whole error messages using the actual text of the errors. Also tell us what steps you take to reproduce the problem. Include details like the names and versions of operating systems. A good rule of thumb is to make sure you define "it", because it's not clear when you say "it tells me to...". What is "it", and what does "it" say, exactly?

Comment: @nmath So basically ubuntu wasn't detecting my windows 10 os so i created 2 partitions, one was a 10gb efi and the other was a 30gb ext2, i installed ubuntu the 30gb, it was installing fine till a fatal error about installing grub or something onto the 30gb partition, after it said it was fine and it said it was finished and it restarted my computer

Comment: So you did this after both operating systems had been installed? Did you follow some instructions to do this? Ubuntu is typically installed to ext4; ext2 really isn't used anymore. Are you sure that both operating systems are viable? We need to know the details of everything you've done, because it sounds like you need to undo a lot of it. It may be more prudent to reinstall.

Comment: I didn't use any guide but the installer told me to use a ext2 so thats why i chose it, and i cant boot into ubuntu or windows as the only option i get is my main normal thing that now just leads to a Grub thingy and it gives an instant error and goes into like recovery mode in Grub, when i have the ubuntu installer in it gives 2 more, one that also does the same thing as main except it was always doing that, and the other that has the same name as the other one except it has UEFI infront of it in its name, that one just boots into the installer for ubuntu

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure what you're referring to... The installer will create partitions for you when you use the default options and AFAIK, there's no suggestions to use ext2 when manually partitioning. At this point you probably need to reinstall. Use the default options so that the installer will take care of all of the dirty work for you.  If Windows is installed as a UEFI OS (likely) then you must also boot the installation USB as UEFI. You will also need enough unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu to get the guided "Install alongside Windows" option. Don't create any partitions ahead of time

Comment: "Just boots the installer..." means you can mount your hard disk from the "Try" installer option and read off any files you want to save.  10GB EFI seems way too big just for the bootloaders 200-300MB should be fine, and only one EFI partition needed per bootable disk.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you messed up your entire HDD by not following any specific guide for dual-boot.

However, considering the fact that your system is dead and nothing gets booted, the only workaround solution is: Reinstalling both Windows and Ubuntu from scratch.

***Note: You will lose out everything that's on your HDD.***

Follow these steps:

- Download gParted, your chosen Windows OS (your preferred version ISO file), Ubuntu OS (preferred version ISO image) and Rufus from their official websites.
- Create a bootable USB for gParted using Rufus & a separate bootable USB for Windows OS.
- Plugin the bootable USB into your system & boot into gParted.Use this guide to avoid messing anything else: [How to use gParted: A quick Guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-GParted)
- Follow the instructions of above guide & remove all the partitions from your HDD, i.e., Format your HDD completely.
- Once done, exit gParted and use your Windows bootable USB to boot into Windows OS and install it on your system.
- Once Windows gets successfully installed, use Rufus again to create another bootable USB with Ubuntu OS
- Follow this guide here to install Ubuntu alongside Windows OS & follow the instructions carefully: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/
- You can decide the partition size for Ubuntu basis your requirements. You don't have to necessarily keep it same as shown in the guide.
- Once you are done installing Ubuntu, perform the following steps to setup your grub menu:
- Boot into `Windows` OS again
- Press `Windows+R` together to open the "Run" dialog.
- Type `cmd` and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to start the command prompt as Administrator. Select "Yes" to the UAC "Do you want to allow ..." dialog.
- Alternatively, right-click on the Start Menu and select "Windows PowerShell (Admin)" (under Windows 10) or "Windows Terminal (Admin)" (under Windows 11).
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit the `Enter` key

**Note:** You do need to have Admin rights in the command prompt before you perform the above action. If `bcdedit` fails, please make sure you are running the prompt as Admin.

Let us know how it works out for you.

Comment: Is there a way without losing anything or just a way to get my files

Comment: Am sorry mate, but I don't think so. Since you're unable to boot into both the Windows and Ubuntu OS, there's no way you can get access to the existing data on your hard disk. 

I will also not recommend you to pay for those expensive paid tools that promise you of data recovery, but never does it 100%. Also, my experience with them hasn't been that great, so that's another reason of why am against them. 

Still, if you want to give them a try, go ahead.

Comment: STOP @Manu Mathur   "Just boots the installer..." means you can mount your hard disk from the "Try" installer option and read off any files you want to save.

Comment: @ManuMathur as long as the file system is intact, you can use it in a live session (Try Ubuntu from installation media). In fact one of the best features of the liveUSB is that it's an excellent rescue disk.

Comment: I fixed the issue by creating a windows installer disk and going to "repair my pc" option, aka the novice linux user of doing things

Comment: That's great, @CorruptDoge. Am glad it worked out for you.

ubfan1 - apologies if my response/comments went too far. Was just trying to help the guy here.

Nmath - Thanks for sharing this insight.

Comment: Always make a backup of your windows system before trying to install a dual boot. Use something like [Aomei](https://www.aomeitech.com/download.html). You can see Windows files in a live session as mentioned above.